# How many people know Batman's identity?

Tags: dc, batman, nolan-batman-trilogy, secret-identity

In Nolan's *Dark Knight* Trilogy,how many people in total actually know that Bruce Wayne is Batman?

Comment: Bruce Wayne knows Batman's secret identity.

Comment: I'd say most people who've seen the movies.

Comment: @RogueJedi I notice he's left out of the answers though--maybe he's in so deep that he doesn't even know anymore?

Comment: How many hot chicks are there in Gotham?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By my count, at least ten.  Six are still living by the end of the third movie.

- Rachel (dead)
- Lucius
- Alfred
- Selina Kyle
- Gordon (finds out at end of 3rd movie)
- John Blake
- Coleman Reese
- Ra's al Ghul (dead)
- Talia (dead)
- Bane (dead)

In *Batman Begins* and *The Dark Knight Rises*, it seems that other members of the League of Shadows know that Wayne is Batman.  We don't know how many or whether they surived.  So, the number could be higher.

Comment: Make sure to toss in the hobo in the first movie.

Comment: How did the hobo know?  Because Batman said "nice coat" to him, which he said to Bruce Wayne earlier in the film?  If so, and the hobo made the connection that it's the same person, I don't think he knew that it was Bruce Wayne who gave him the coat.

Answer (score 3):

Within the Dark Knight Trilogy, Batman's identity is well concealed.

**Alfred** and **Lucius Fox** obviously know since they're working with him, as does **Ra's al Ghul**, **Bane** and the **other members of the League of Shadows** such as

> Talia

Since they were instrumental in his training.

**Jim Gordon** also works out his identity at the end of the film series, as does **John Blake** and **Selina Kyle**. **Coleman Reese** *strongly suspects* (albeit this knowledge isn't explicitly confirmed within the film) and **Rachel** also learns his identity. As Rogue Jedi points out in his [comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/125886/how-many-people-know-this-secret/125887#comment314342_125886), **Bruce Wayne** is also aware of Bruce Wayne's secret identity.

11 *named* individuals, but potentially ***dozens*** of others.

Comment: Rachel knows that he's Batman, as does Fox.

Comment: Lucius Fox, also knows

Comment: @tilley31 - Well duh. How could I miss him.

Comment: Did Harvey Dent ever know?

Comment: @Skooba - Not in the Nolan-verse, as far as I'm aware.